# Creating a new raster based on pixel value of original raster using raster calculator but new layer is not evident

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, conditional, extract-by-mask

I am trying to create a new raster based on a current raster (w001001 - NVIS) which has one paletted band, with palette values ranging from 1 to 29, with each palette/value representing a vegetation type (e.g. 1 = rain forests).

I want to create a new raster (actually, preferably a vector, but I cross that bridge later) for the palette of value 3 (this one):

[image]

I have followed the answers to the questions posted in this forum, and have used the Raster Calculator to do this:

[image]

It all seems to process fine, and the new layer appears in my layer list. However, I can't see the layer at all and when I use the [image] nothing comes up. When I open properties for the layer, metadata tells me this:

[image]

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

This is my first post and I am a fairly new user of QGIS so apologies if anything is unclear or nonsensical.

Comment: Could you share the 'w001001 - NVIS' raster?

Comment: Try with quotes "w001001 - NVIS@1" = 3

Comment: Thanks- that seems to have done something. WHen I zoom to layer extent (which didn't work without the " marks) it takes me out somewhere completely off from where my original map was- so looks like I have made some error with the positioning of the new layer somehow… I'll have a play around

Comment: So, my problem was the projection of the layer (possibly because my raster layer was a w001001 file from an ESRI raster, and didn't have the projection information attached to it). I fixed this by first "zoom to current extent" on my original (w001001 - NVIS) layer. Then, in the raster calculator I clicked on current layer extent, which appears to have given my extracted layer the correct projection.